# Query on iteration

Tags: java, iteration

I want to written a object holding data read from xml

```
    String data = null;
   while ((data = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
               logger.info("Data:"+data);
    }
```

i want to return a obj holding the complete data read in while loop,how would i do that?
its java

Comment: It would help people to know what programming language you are using. Iteration is a general concept in many languages...

Comment: Kaleb - this could be C# as well, or another C based Object Oriented language.

Comment: If it was C#, String wouldn't be capitalized, so I figured it was probably Java.  All her other questions are about Java too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a StringBuffer to combine all the lines, then output to a String when your loop is done:

```
String data = null;
StringBuffer dataBuffer = new StringBuffer();
while ((data = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    logger.info("Data:"+data);
    dataBuffer.append(data).append("\n");
}
String completeData = dataBuffer.toString();
```

Comment: This is not working out,data holds the complete xml in while loop 
  logger.info("Data:"+data); will print the xml in console,i want the same data object to be returned outside while.

Comment: @sarah, just return the completeData object, and comment out the logger call. The logger call is just to show you sausages being made.

Comment: its not working out
the while loop data will have the complete xml,when i am using this
dataBuffer.append(data).append("\n");
}
String completeData = dataBuffer.toString();
and trying to pring completeData i wont get the xml itself

Comment: I got the output that isa the complete data,but the complete data should be only xml its appending some other data also like
curl -o xyz<?xml></xml>
i need to read only from xml trimming curl -0 xyz data,how to do so?

Comment: Where do you get the input data from?  I assumed it was from an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Google for "DOM XML parser" plus the name of your programming language. Maybe add "tutorial".